# Problemas em fazer a build android no Cordova

Tags: android, apache, apache-cordova, phonegap-buillder

```
Failed to restore plugin "cordova-plugin-file-transfer" from config.xml. You might need to try adding it again. Error: Version of installed plugin: "cordova-plugin-file@6.0.2" does not satisfy dependency plugin requirement "cordova-plugin-file@^4.0.0". Try --force to use installed plugin as dependency.
```

Também fala que o SDK não foi encontrado, mas ele está nas variáveis de ambiente. Além disso ele não encontra a JDK.

Nunca usei o Cordova, e preciso fazer uma build para a versão 5.1 do android

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: Ele dá o seguinte erro.]

Comment: Mas, vc tem o SDK do Android instalado na máquina?

Comment: Sim, creio que sim, basta setar as variáveis de sistema, correto? (Comecei com android faz pouco tempo) Tenho a JDK e ele também não encontra

Comment: Não, vc tem que baixar o SDK, aconselho a baixar o Android Studio que já pré configura quase tudo. Cordova é bem mais complicado do que está imaginando.

Comment: Então, eu tenho o Android Studio e, inclusive, já fiz uma mini aplicação nele, realmente estou sem saber o que acontece.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problema resolvido, tive que fazer o downgrade do JDK e SDK para funcionar.
Entretanto, persiste outro problema:

PS C:\Users\felsilva\Desktop\backup\cordova\gps> cordova build android
Cannot read property '1' of null